# On the convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(f(x)-T_n\{f\}(x))$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

To test the efficiency of the Taylor Series at approximating functions, I was wondering whether$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(f(x)-T_n\{f\}(x))\tag{$\star$}$$converges, where $T_n\{f\}(x)$ is the degree $n$ Taylor polynomial for $f(x)$. Finding a closed form for this infinite sum would also be interesting. Analyzing the partial sums of this series: $$\sum_{n=0}^y\left(f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^kf^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\right)=(y+1)f(x)-\sum_{n=0}^y\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^kf^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\tag{1}$$Using the identity: $$\sum_{n=0}^x\sum_{k=0}^na_k=\sum_{k=0}^x(x+1-k)a_k$$for some sequence $a_k$ that could depend on variables other than $k$, we could rewrite $(1)$ as $$(y+1)f(x)-\sum_{n=0}^y\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^kf^{(k)}(0)}{k!}=(y+1)(f(x)-T_y\{f\}(x))+xT_y\{f'\}(x)$$Taking the limit as $y\rightarrow\infty$, we get that $(\star)$ is equal to $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(f(x)-T_n\{f\}(x))=xf'(x)+\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}y(f(x)-T_y\{f\}(x))$$Using that $f(x)-\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}T_y\{f\}(x)=0$. The limit may converge only for particular $f(x)$. For example, when $f(x)$ is constant the series is trivially $0$.

I am looking for one (or more) of the following

1. Proving the convergence of the infinite series.
2. Finding a closed form for this series, at least for one or more linearly independent functions that aren't polynomials.
3. Asymptotic analysis and approximations for the infinite series.

In summary, a study of $(\star)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$ T_{n,a}\{f\}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k $$

denote the degree $n$ Taylor polynomial of $f$ about $a$. Then we prove:

> **Theorem.** Let $f$ be analytic near $x = 0$ with radius of convergence $R \in (0, \infty]$. Then for any $|x| < R$,
>
> $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[ f(x) - T_{n,0}\{f\}(x) \right] = x f'(x). $$

*Proof.* Using the [integral form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder),

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{N} \left[ f(x) - T_{n,0}\{f\}(x) \right]
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x - t)^n \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{x} \sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!} (x - t)^n \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{x} T_{N,t}\{f'\}(x) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= x f'(x) - \int_{0}^{x} \left[f'(x) - T_{N,t}\{f'\}(x) \right] \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= x f'(x) - \int_{0}^{x} \int_{t}^{x} \frac{f^{(N+2)}(s)}{N!} (x - s)^{N}  \, \mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t \\
&= x f'(x) - \int_{0}^{x} \frac{f^{(N+2)}(s)}{N!} s (x - s)^{N}  \, \mathrm{d}s.
\end{align*}

To give a uniform bound of this remainder, fix $\rho \in (|x|, R)$. Then a bit of complex analysis tells that, for $|s| \leq |x|$, we have a bound

\begin{align*}
|f^{(k)}(s)|
&= \left| \frac{k!}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|=\rho} \frac{f(z)}{(z - s)^{k+1}} \, \mathrm{d}z \right|
\leq \frac{k! \rho}{(\rho - |s|)^{k+1}} M
\end{align*}

where $M = \max_{|z|=\rho} |f(z)|$. Plugging this back and noting that $x$ and $s$ always have the same sign, we get

\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{f^{(N+2)}(s)}{N!} s (x - s)^{N} \right|
&\leq \frac{|s| (|x| - |s|)^{N}}{N!} \frac{(N+2)!\rho}{(\rho - |s|)^{N+3}} M \\
&\leq \frac{|x|\rho M}{(\rho - |x|)^3} (N+1)(N+2) \left( \frac{|x|}{\rho} \right)^N.
\end{align*}

Since $\frac{|x|}{\rho} < 1$, this bound decays exponentially fast as $N \to \infty$, proving the desired claim.

Comment: Overkill but I like how complex analysis was used. I never thought of using the formula for the $k$th derivative of an analytic function to solve any related problem and found it useless until I saw your answer.

Answer (score 0):

We could re-write $(\star)$ as follows: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(f(x)-T_n\{f\}(x))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{x^kf^{(k)}(0)}{k!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx^nf^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx^{n-1}f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=xf'(x)$$Which means that $$\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}y\left(f(x)-T_n\{f\}(x)\right)=0$$